# Как обработать событие по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Нажимаю на кнопку и нужно обработать это событие в jquery.

Но не знаю как реализовать это в самом js-коде.

В кнопку `onclick=''` - не подходит, нужно что-то типа

```
document.onclick ('.button') = function ({
... 
});
```

Comment: вы хоть что-то пытались читать про `jquery`, или пытаетесь придумать как это сделать с помощью фантазии своей?

Comment: @teran Топикстартер не читатель, топикстартер - программист.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  // ваш код
});
```

Comment: Не работает у меня

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае необходимо использовать такой синтаксис

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
   //some logic here
});
```

Посмотреть можно [тут](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Не работает у меня

Comment: что именно у вас не работает? Вы данный код вообще вызываете?

Answer (score 0):

```js
button = document.getElementById('button');

function fn() {
  console.log("click");
};

if (button.addEventListener) {
  button.addEventListener('click', fn, false); // для ие
} else if (button.attachEvent)  {
  button.attachEvent('onclick', fn); // для остальных
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Тык!</button>
```

**Зачем использовать addEventListener?**

> addEventListener - это способ зарегистрировать обработчик события,
>   описанный в документации W3C DOM. Вот список преимуществ его
>   использования:

- Позволяет добавлять множество обработчиков для одного события. Это особенно полезно для DHTML библиотек или Mozilla extensions, которые должны работать в условиях использования сторонних библиотек/расширений.
- Предоставляет точный контроль фазы срабатывания(вызова) обработчика
  (захват или всплытие)
- Срабатывает на любом DOM элементе, а не только на HTML элементах.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('.button_order').click(function () {
        alert('hello!');
    });
}
```

Нужно было ставить код или после кнопок (в конце документа), или подождать, пока документ загрузится.

Так работает. Всем спасибо за помощь